# Vim interface on web browser input fields?

Tags: vim, browser, chrome

I am looking for a browser plugin which inputs textin of input boxes with the same keyboard interface of the Vim text editor.  I have adopted [Vimium](http://vimium.github.com/) which makes general navigation much more effective, however I often find my self wish I had the Vim interface while I have selected an input field (like while I'm creating this post).  I would very much like to be able to navigate the text in the same way I edit file with the vim text editor and I am curious if such a plugin exists?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36257/vim-interface-on-web-browser-input-fields || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75652/is-there-a-firefox-add-on-to-use-vim-to-edit-textboxes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Pentadactyl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pentadactyl/) and Vimperator addons for Firefox allow vim-like editing in text areas by pressing `ctrl+t`; I think there is also an option to turn it on permanenly. There is also [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) that will actually launch an editor for you.

As far as Chrome goes, it's not as easy, as the API is quite limited. They require you to run a server on your system. There was [TextareaConnect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ooddekcmdpjicehjkgobdopbkgepmahj), but it appears to be broken right now.

Comment: I have finally dove into pentadactyll extension and I am very impressed!

Comment: Note for re-discoverers: The latest versions of Firefox no longer support pentadactyl and vimperator

Comment: For a similar solution that works today, you can use Tridactyl, as per my answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582247/28896

Answer (score 11):

[wasavi](http://appsweets.net/wasavi) provides a vim interface for text boxes in multiple web browsers (Chrom(ium), Firefox/Iceweasel & Opera) and I can confirm that it works on Chromium on Linux (Debian 7 w/ Gnome3). Start it with `<Ctrl><Enter>`, lots more info on the home page below:

[wasavi home page](http://appsweets.net/wasavi/)

[Github page](https://github.com/akahuku/wasavi)

[for Chrom(ium)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wasavi/dgogifpkoilgiofhhhodbodcfgomelhe)

Links for installing to Opera and Firefox/Iceweasel can be found on the home page (link above - I did include them but I can't post with more than 2 links...)

Comment: It appears to lack visual block mode (at least in chrome) which is a big drawback, to me at least.

Comment: It also doesn't work with the hypothes.is on Chrome...

Comment: As for the visual block mode, here's the feature request (open since 2015): https://github.com/akahuku/wasavi/issues/104

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Shawn's answer, pentadactyl (and vimperator) allow you to press `ctrl+i` when in an text field to actually edit it in vim. It will save the contents of the text field to a temporary file, open that file in (g)vim, and read the (changed) contents back after closing the editor.

Comment: this should be added a comment to his answer.

Comment: I agree that it would have been better there, yeah. But I don't have enough rep to do that, and I did feel this was a valuable addition (as I personally find this feature quite useful), so I decided to do it this way instead. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

A very modern solution to this problem is [glacambre's Firenvim](https://github.com/glacambre/firenvim/issues), which automatically overlays text input boxes with a neovim window that syncs to the content of that text box. This uses your system neovim, with associated config and plugins(!).
Subjectively, I have found it to be a significantly smoother experience than alternatives like It's All Text, or even wasavi. In addition, it has a full modern neovim implementation rather than a custom vi-like implementation, so using it involves much less context switching than wasavi, vimsert, or vimperator (which is no longer supported on modern firefox).

Firenvim supports Firefox and Chrome officially, and other Chrome-like browsers unofficially.

It does, however, require neovim to be installed, and because you are typing in an Nvim UI, you lose things like the textbox's native font (nvim cannot support non-monospaced fonts).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Chrome, I recently release an open source Chrome extension called Vimsert. It'll let you edit any textarea within the Ace editor's vim-mode.

https://github.com/gabesullice/vimsert

Comment: it appears to have problems on the stackexchange and sharelatex sites though (ctrl+i is caught by the webpage and makes text italic, rather than launching the extension)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform a textarea into a vim-like code editor, this [bookmarklet](http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/build/demo/bookmarklet/) allow you to transform any textarea into an [ace](http://ace.c9.io) by clicking three times on it. It support vim and emacs keybindings. You can select these at the bookmarklet creation page.

Answer (score 1):

[Tridactyl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tridactyl-vim/) is probably what you're looking for nowadays, assuming you're willing to use Firefox.

It's the spiritual successor to the likes of Pentadactyl and Vimperator, which are not available for the current version of Firefox.

If you want something more like It's All Text, where the editing area appears right on top of the browser text area rather than launching an editor window, and you're willing to use Neovim, check out [firenvim](https://github.com/glacambre/firenvim).

Answer (score 1):

GhostText - https://github.com/fregante/GhostText will synchronize typing in any of the supported editors (include Vim)

Answer (score -1):

I think the key <kbd>F</kbd> is your answer, so that it mark all input boxes with a number, then hit the number with which input field you want, as simple as it is. Enjoy it!